# Is checking the existence of file or folder blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: c, linux

Is checking the existence of file or folder blocking or non-blocking?

```
access( fname, F_OK ) // blocking ?
```

Is opening dir / file blocking or non-blocking?

```
opendir(dir); // blocking?
open(fd..); // blocking?
```

Is list dir blocking or non-blocking?

```
readdir // blocking?
```

By block, I mean take a long time to return.

Comment: What do you mean by blocking?

Comment: How would `access` block anything? (waiting on what?)

Comment: Yes, yes, that's the security-hole aspect of it if checking for access before calling `open`, but since it isn't going to wait for what it is checking to be created if it doesn't already exist, I don't think it could block anything.

Comment: Y'all are using some totally different sense of the term "block" from the way it's used in Unix system programming.  I understand OP to be asking whether these operations can potentially involve a lengthy wait for I/O to complete, and the answer to that is _yes_.

Comment: How was the file opened? You need to show the full call to `open`, and not `...`. Did you use `O_NONBLOCK`? If `O_NONBLOCK` was used, then [`open (2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) should not block.

Comment: @jww That manpage is wrong. `open(..., O_NONBLOCK)` can and will block at least for the duration of the path traversal and permissions checks, which cannot be postponed, and which may involve multiple network round-trips.

Comment: would be good to hear from OP on the meaning of the blocking in the question before trying to answer it.

Comment: @Serge In the context of a list of Unix filesystem operations, it's really hard for me to imagine that they could have meant anything else.

Comment: Some people use the word "block" to mean "take a long time". Some people use the word "block" to main "wait for I/O". Some people use the word "block" to mean "enter an interruptible wait state". The question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I assume that you mean "block" in the sense that it's usually used in Unix manpages and related documentation: that is, you are asking whether these operations can involve the calling process waiting for an extended period for I/O to complete.  If this is not what you mean please edit your question to clarify.)

The short answer is that all of these system calls can potentially block.

The long answer:

- checking for the existence of a file or folder: *never do this*, it introduces a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race condition into your program.  In 20 years of Unix system programming I have literally never encountered a situation where the `access` system call was the right thing to use.  Instead just go ahead and attempt to open the file, enter the directory, whatever, and check whether that failed.

  Having said that, `access`, `stat`, and `lstat` can block for the same reasons `open` can (discussed below).  `fstat` is not *guaranteed* not to block but usually it's ok to assume it won't.
- `open` and `opendir` can block, *even if you use `O_NONBLOCK`*.  The most common case where this happens is when the file or directory you're trying to open is on a remote file system, so finding out whether the file exists and you're allowed to access it involves sending packets over the network.

  There isn't any way around this within the POSIX API because there's no way to represent an in-progress `open` operation.  The networking API separates the creation of a socket (`socket`, which can't block) from the request to connect it to a remote peer (`connect`, which can), so when `connect` returns −1 with errno set to `EINPROGRESS`, you already know the socket descriptor number and you can `select` on it.  If `open` were to give you `EINPROGRESS` you wouldn't have a file descriptor to `select` on.
- `readdir` can block for all the same reasons plain old `read` can block.  Again, the most common case where you'd notice is when the directory is on a remote file system.  The problem in this case is the `DIR` abstraction gets in the way of requesting non-blocking I/O in the normal fashion.

Comment: `fstat` can easily block (potentially for many minutes) for a file on an nfs mount (network file system) with automount set.

Comment: Thank you, there's no remote server, only local disk. will it block too?

Comment: @garen96 Yes, disk accesses can be quite slow.  Recently I had a `tar` operation hang for _hours_ inside an `open` (with `O_CREAT`) because the filesystem it was trying to write to was on a RAID array undergoing rebuild.

Comment: Due to Linux's modular structure, it is possible (and reasonably practical) for a mounted filesystem to call a [fuse filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) implemented on a streaming system of some sort (magnetic tape).  It isn't hard to imagine how long it might take, even though it "is local".